# maven plugin out of date

Tags: java, spring, maven, plugins

When I want to start a new maven project in STS and make my first simple spring project from tutorial JavaBrains I received this error:

```
Cannot read lifecycle mapping metadata for artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:maven-plugin:2.6.1:runtime Cause: error in opening zip file
```

I dont know what happen...

my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>io.test.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>course-api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Test Spring API</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version> // i try another version and this same..
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the contents from the below folder can help fixing this issue. Hope this helps.

C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-jar-plugin\

Then run: mvn clean install

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the existing versions from your local maven repository.
Then run a clean install with -U option.

Answer (score 0):

it seems issue with your pom.xml file,

1. Make sure `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>` is    available in the repository, looks like you have edited artifact name as `<spring-boot-starter-**parent**>.`
2. Your second console says that you have commented single line using `<//>` in your `pom.xml`so it's printing as ***`expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...</version>\r\n\t</parent>\r\n\`***  use `<!-- -->` to comment in `pom.xml` file.

Hope this helps to resolve.

Comment: I'm download this time correctly and this same problem with: maven-clean-plugin-2.6.1.jar

Comment: you meant to say that you have corrected your pom.xml file and parent dependency available??

Comment: i'm sure, i try to manually replace new maven-clean-plugin and try other parent RELEASE version and this same problem with different plugin

Comment: Hope you've added maven <plugin> in your pom.xml <build> tag, please select your project and press Alt+F5 and Mark Force update of snapshot/releases and then click on OK, even after if you face same issue, please post your console.